# Upscaling SQL Server and Database structures

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am SQL Server programmer, new SQL Server infrastructure has been bought, as we observed the performance bottlenecks with almost 5 times more the capacity we have. Now we have to think what database deployment structure should be

We were having following challenges:

1. Dead locks
2. Multiple applications and same database
3. SQL query performance issues
4. Number of application users will be increase by 2 times

The plan we have:

1. Separating application databases (to reduce the deadlocks, but will result in repeating master data)
2. Separate reporting database (use of SQL Server replication - don't know cons yet)
3. Load balancing for application servers (will increase concurrent transactions)
4. The database has been upgraded to SQL Server 2014
5. Fine tuning T-SQL code

As mentioned above we shall have a single server with increased capacity

Questions:

1. Can separate application databases help us?
2. Will having separate reporting database help us?
3. What kind of technique to replicate the data is best one on a single server with proven results.. I have heard of Sync also
4. Can techniques like data partitioning help us? how?
5. Any suggestions of specific fine tuning area? technique?
6. Any additional suggestions

Comment: Without the background information it's not possible to answer to this. Why are there deadlocks? Did you try to improve your code / database structure to reduce them? Are they from single source (application, table etc) or all over the place?

Comment: As a quick note, replication to reporting database can help, if you have huge report queries that keep on blocking updates. Partitioning can cause even more issues, and mostly helps on db maintenance etc.

Comment: What is the bottleneck you got - CPU, memory, disk io? (Hardware?) ...are you doing massive inserts and/or mostly reading? Dedicated machine or webserver on it too - how many network connections to web server?

Comment: Yes we are trying to improve our code. Can you please give hint how DB structure will solve the deadlock challenges? They are on particular tables. There are delete and insert operations while master data update jobs are running. There are around 2000 users logging into system concurrently.